# Serialization error when using a non-serializable object in driver code

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using Spark Streaming to process a stream by processing each partition (saving events to HBase), then ack the last event in each RDD from the driver to the receiver, so the receiver can ack it to its source in turn.

```java
public class StreamProcessor {

  final AckClient ackClient;

  public StreamProcessor(AckClient ackClient) {
    this.ackClient = ackClient;
  }

  public void process(final JavaReceiverInputDStream<Event> inputDStream)
    inputDStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
      JavaRDD<Event> lastEvents = rdd.mapPartition(events -> {
        // ------ this code executes on the worker -------
        // process events one by one; I don't use ackClient here
        // return the event with the max delivery tag here
      });
      // ------ this code executes on the driver -------
      Event lastEvent = .. // find event with max delivery tag across partitions
      ackClient.ack(lastEvent); // use ackClient to ack last event
    });
  }
}
```

The problem here is that I get the following error (even though everything seems to work fine):

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:602)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.mapPartitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.mapPartitions(JavaRDD.scala:32)
...
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: <some non-serializable object used by AckClient>
...
```

It seems that Spark is trying to serialize `AckClient` to send it to the workers, but I thought that only code inside `mapPartitions` is serialized/shipped to the workers, and that the code at the RDD level (i.e. inside `foreachRDD` but not inside `mapPartitions`) would not be serialized/shipped to the workers.

Can someone confirm if my thinking is correct or not? And if it is correct, should this be reported as a bug?

Comment: What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this was fixed in 1.1. However, if you look at the stack trace, the cleaner that is throwing is being invoked in the `mapPartitions`

> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1435)
>
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:602)

So, the problem has to do with your `mapPartitions`. Make sure that you aren't accidentally wrapping `this`, as that is a common issue

Comment: OK, so in the actual code we are actually accessing other members of the `StreamProcessor` class from within `mapPartitions`, so does that mean the entire class, along with its members is being serialized/shipped to the workers?

Comment: But I'm not calling a method on the class, I'm calling methods on objects that are members of the class, e.g. `this.hbaseClient.save(...)`. Would this also cause the `StreamProcessor` class to be serialized?

Comment: Yes, you are still calling `this`